# Change position of Chapter number and word "chapter" on chapter title page

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

I am writing my thesis in Latex and would like to create a nice chapter title page.
I would like to place the chapter number and the word chapter on the right side, slightly overlapping the image I inserted at the bottom. Further, I would like to increase the size of the chapter number and the word chapter. I would like the chapter title to stay where it is. Additionally, I would like the dummy text to be positioned below the chapter title. I have tried a lot, but cannot seem to figure out how this works.

I have attached a picture of what I am aiming for.[image]

Please see my MWE below. I would be grateful for any help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt, final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% custom section headers
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% I added this
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{ \normalsize \LARGE  \color{black}}  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.9,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (current page.south){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=10cm]{blue.jpg}};
    \flushright \large \color{RoyalRed} \MakeUppercase { \chaptertitlename}%
        \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter}}
  }
  {10pt}{\bfseries\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-70pt}{180pt} 

\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Thank you for your feedback!.

Comment: Tested in Oveleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. (I understood that the figure goes at the top of the page.)

Change the font size of the word chapter and of the chapter number using `\fontsize{<size>}{<skip>}`. Modify their position using `xshift` and `yshift`

Also    `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{<space left>}{<space above>}{<space below>}` for the chapter title.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt, final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% custom section headers
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % added to change fonts with pdflatex <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}

\newcommand{\ChapLabel}{\fontsize{36pt}{44pt}\selectfont \color{RoyalRed} \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}% set the word Chapter
\newcommand{\ChapNum}{\fontsize{120pt}{144pt}\selectfont \color{RoyalRed} \thechapter}% set the chapter number
\newcommand{\MakeChap}{\ChapLabel\enspace\ChapNum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{ \normalsize \LARGE  \color{black}}  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
    \node(blue)[opacity=0.9,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north] at (current page.north){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=10cm]{blue.jpg}};
    \node [below= of blue.south east, anchor=base east, xshift=-\marginparsep, yshift=-1ex] {\MakeChap};
\end{tikzpicture}}
{10pt}{\bfseries\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{170pt}{20pt} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[2-8]    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question. (Figure at the bottom and subtitles.)

Use `\Schapter{<chapter title>}{<subtitle>}` to add a subtitle.

[image: y]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt, final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
% custom section headers
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{anyfontsize} % added for change fonts with pdflatex <<<<<<<<<<<<<   
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% style plain >>> empty for chapter page
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}

\newcommand{\ChapLabel}{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\selectfont \color{RoyalRed}\sffamily \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}% set the word Chapter
\newcommand{\ChapNum}{\fontsize{120pt}{144pt}\selectfont \color{RoyalRed}\sffamily \thechapter}% set the chapter number
\newcommand{\MakeChap}{\vspace*{10cm}\ChapLabel\enspace\ChapNum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{ \normalsize \LARGE  \color{black}}  {%
    \enlargethispage{-7cm}
    \begin{figure}[b]%      
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
                \node(blue)[opacity=0.9,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (current page.south){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=10cm]{blue.jpg}};
                \node (chap) [above= of blue.north east, anchor=south east, xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth-30pt, yshift=-4ex] {\ChapLabel};
                \node [right= of chap.south east, anchor=base west, xshift= -\marginparwidth+12ex, yshift=-6ex] {\ChapNum};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}}       
{10pt}{\bfseries\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

\newcommand{\Schapter}[2]{\chapter[#1]{#1\\[1ex] \parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\large#2}}}% add subtitles <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}    
    \Schapter{Introduction}{Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus}
    \lipsum[2-8]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your fast answers :-) Actually, I was aiming for a combination of both your solutions. The blue picture should stay at the bottom. The overlap of the blue image with the chapter number and word chapter you created are perfect. Unfortunately, the look different from what you posted when I compile them in overleaf. Further, I tried to modify \newcommand{\ChapLabel}{\fontsize{36pt}{44pt} \newcommand{\ChapNum}{\fontsize{120pt}{144pt}\selectfont  but I doesn't have any effect in my own example.

Comment: I did not mention this, however the lipsum text is supposed to be a subtitle. Would you be able to show me how to define this as a subtitle? I tried to draw what I was aiming for, I will add it to my post. Thanks a lot again you two!

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt, final]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\refstepcounter{chapter}%
\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
\else
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\if@twocolumn
\@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
\else
\@makechapterhead{#2}%
\@afterheading
\fi\clearpage}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\lipsum[2]}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[opacity=0.9,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south] at (current page.south){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=10cm]{blue.jpg}};}\par%
    {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip 4.2cm\flushright\Huge\color{RoyalRed} \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space%
    \rlap{\scalebox{5}{\thechapter}}
    \par\nobreak
    \fi}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]